# Why is mintty not flushing stdout on program termination when using PlaySound?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw

I am experimenting with using the [PlaySound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd743680(v=vs.85)) of the Win32 API under MinGW64.

My code is below. I compile with `gcc hello.c -lwinmm`

```c
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // if I manually disable buffering or flush stdout, I see the messages
    // otherwise, I don't
    //setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("hello\n");
    PlaySound(argv[1], NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    printf("goodbye\n");
    //fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

I see `hello` and `goodbye` for each of the following scenarios:

- If I remove the call to `PlaySound`
- If I disable buffering to `stdout` or manually flush it
- If I run the program in the windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`)

But I do not see the messages when I run the program in `mintty` (the results are identical for `stderr` and also when using `_IOLBF`). It seems as though the flushing of the standard streams at program termination is disabled when `PlaySound` is called, though I have no idea why that would be. It appears as though the program is terminating normally.

I ran `strace` on the program and I noticed that 5 threads are spawned in the process of `PlaySound`. Could that have something to do with it?

```
--- Process 4176 created
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 0000000076ff0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 0000000076dd0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 000007fefd010000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll at 000007feff240000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll at 000007fef8c60000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll at 0000000076ef0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll at 000007fefe3a0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll at 000007fefec50000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll at 000007fefed90000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll at 000007fefe710000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll at 000007fefe100000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll at 000007fefd2f0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll at 000007fefe5e0000
--- Process 4176 thread 4844 created
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll at 000007fefafa0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll at 000007fefae40000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll at 000007fefea40000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll at 000007fefee60000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll at 000007fefe290000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\wdmaud.drv at 000007fef62e0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ksuser.dll at 0000000072560000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\avrt.dll at 000007fefad90000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll at 000007fefefc0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll at 000007fefd2b0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll at 000007fefd1f0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll at 000007fefe210000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\AudioSes.dll at 000007fef60c0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv at 000007fef62d0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll at 000007fef60a0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll at 000007fef6090000
--- Process 4176 thread 2780 created
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll at 000007fefce50000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll at 000007feff1a0000
--- Process 4176 thread 4420 created
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll at 000007fefadc0000
--- Process 4176 loaded C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll at 000007fefa900000
--- Process 4176 thread 9992 created
--- Process 4176 thread 6992 created
--- Process 4176 thread 2780 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 4176 thread 4420 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 4176 thread 6992 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 4176 thread 4844 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 4176 thread 9992 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 4176 exited with status 0x0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in the same environment(MinGW64), added delays and

```
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
```

that output hello and Goodbye properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#include<mmsystem.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
   printf("hello\n");
   PlaySound(TEXT("Alarm01.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
   Sleep(5000);
   printf("goodbye\n");
   fflush(stdout);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I disable buffering on stdout or fflush stdout, then I see the messages, but my expectation is that I should not have to do either of these because stdout should be closed (and thus flushed) at program termination. Do you still see the output when you remove these but leave the `Sleep(5000)`?

Comment: Yes, I can see the output. You can tell me your environment version and I will test it again.

Comment: How bizarre: whether I get output seems to be a complex function of whether I add `SND_ASYNC`, `SND_LOOP`, add a call to `Sleep`, how long I sleep for, and whether I have a loop that does nothing. Example: if I add `| SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP` and Sleep for at least 30 ms, I  get output, or if I don't sleep at all, but not if I sleep for 20 ms. If instead I just have a loop, I only need to add `SND_ASYNC` to get output.
My `mintty` version is 3.5.2 if that helps.

Comment: Do you mean that your program is unstable? I will try to test with your version.